# Отображение подзаголовков в категории. PHP и MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

У меня появился вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы на странице категории подгружались подзаголовки, под которыми уже отображались конечные статьи?

Сейчас MySql есть 2 связанные между собой таблицы: sections и articles.

Таблица section, допустим выглядит так

**category_id** | **id** | **name**
1 | 1 | n1
1 | 2 | n2
2 | 3 | n3
2 | 4 | n1
3 | 5 | n2
3 | 6 | n3

Таблица articles так:

**id | section_id | name**
1 | 1 | name1
2 | 1 | name2
3 | 2 | name3
4 | 2 | name4
5 | 3 | name5

Получается, что например страница категории 1 должна выглядеть следующим образом

**Подзаголовок n1**
 статья name1
 статья name2
**Подзаголовок n2**
 статья name3
 статья name4

Подзаголовки в разных категориях разные, стандартизировать их не получится. Понятно, что отображение статей для категории реализуется с помощью get параметров, но в данном случае их нет.
Пока получилось в каждой категории отобразить нужные подзаголовки, а дальше либо по одной статье везде (если объединять таблицы и использовать group by), либо, наоборот, в каждом подзаголовке все статьи из категории. А как отсортировать нужные ума не приложу, уже весь интернет перерыл.
Если нет готового варианта решения, то, как считаете, в какую сторону думать? У самого пока были идеи или вводить переменную, определяющую section_id, но как связать ее с mysql запросом? Или каким-нибудь способом использовать concat.
Самый-самый крайний вариант - это на каждую страницу добавить все возможные подзаголовки (всего штук 15-20, а на каждой странице 3-4) и не отображать те, для которых ничего не будет в таблице найдено. Но это фигня какая-то, да и тоже пока не очень понятно как реализовывать

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sc.name, art.* FROM section AS sc
JOIN articles AS art ON art.section_id = sc.id
WHERE sc.category_id = 'Нужный id категории'
```

Comment: Попробовал, получилось выводит в таком виде:
Подзаголовок 1  
 статья 1  
Подзаголовок 1  
 статья 2  
Подзаголовок 2  
статья 3  
Подзаголовок 2  
статья 4  


Как можно избежать дублирования заголовков?

Comment: @Алексей , я не знаю. Мне никогда не было это нужно.

Comment: @Алексей , поэтому я создал отдельный вопрос - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/646313/%D0%92-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-sql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT('Подзаголовок ', name) name, /* id, */ 0
FROM section
WHERE category_id IN ( @category_id_list )
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('статья ', articles.name), /* id, */ id
FROM section, articles
WHERE section.id = articles.id  
  AND section.category_id IN ( @category_id_list )
ORDER BY 2 /* , 3 */
```

Если на странице выводится несколько категорий - раскомментируй дополнительное поле.

Comment: Сами слова "подзаголовок" и "статья" отображаться не должны, получается concat не нужен?

А в php как эти два запроса потом объединить? Ведь если запускать два перебора массива, то статьи будут выводиться столько же раз, сколько подзаголовков в категории

Comment: Какие такие "эти два" запроса? у меня ОДИН запрос.

Comment: так этот запрос вернет сначала список всех подразделов подряд, а затем список всех статей подряд, а не подраздел->статьи, или я не прав?