# В каком формате возвращается ответ на SQL запрос?

Tags: sql, хранение-данных

Представьте, что мы делаем SQL-запрос к нашей базе данных. Мы хотим получить записи, скажем, из двух связанных таблиц (один ко многим). Мы делаем простой запрос, соединяя таблицы обычным JOIN-ом. Мы получаем какую-ту структуру, которую преобразуем в массив, одна ячейка которого соответствует одной строке из ответа.

Вспомним, что связь у нас один ко многим, а значит может быть несколько строк с одинаковыми значениями, соответсвующие одной и той же строке из первой таблицы, просто они дополнены какими-то уникальными значениями из второй, поэтому требуют отдельной строки.

То есть имеем дублирование данных. Это нехорошо, так как это занимает лишнюю память.

Вопрос: когда наша база данных возвращает ответ, он также содержит это дублирование? Если это не так, то как он устроен? А если так, то можно ли как-то избежать дублирования?

Comment: Обычно да. СУБД, чаще всего, это отдельный сервер. Он просто не может вернуть сложную структуру - отдает по строкам. Хотя мне попадались и возвраты по столбцам... Возможно, при некоторых настройках драйверов работы с БД такое реализовать можно. Но, лично я (на РНР) сам обрабатываю данные с дублированием и программно (не-СУБД) собираю нужную структуру

Comment: Используйте `select distinct` для того что б убирать дубли строк

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Протоколы передачи данных между SQL (SQL Server, MySQL) и клиентским кодом обычно не предусматривают устранения дублей. По крайней мере SQL Server [Tabular Data Streaming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee320917(v=sql.105).aspx) передает дубликаты как есть, хотя при этом умеет достаточно много всего, включая мультиплексирование.

Основная причина отсутствия дедупликации - потоковая схема выборки и передачи данных. Сервер выдает строки на клиент по мере их готовности, и тут же выбрасывает из памяти. Для дедупликации их пришлось бы хранить и сравнивать с новыми строками.

Со стороны клиента то же самое - строки можно принимать и обрабатывать по одной. Например, вы можете рендерить html по мере поступления данных из SQL, без вычитывания всего датасета. И начать отдавать ответ браузеру еще до того, как SQL дочитает последнюю строку с диска.

Ну и опять же - CPU и память обычно более узкое место, чем сеть между серверами - поэтому делается выбор в пользу экономии CPU. Проще передать лишние байты, чем тратить время на анализ дубликатов.

Answer (score 2):

SQL основан на так называемой [реляционной алгебре](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0). Это математически строгая теория, замкнутая относительно определенных операций.

Если выражаться простым языком - это правила манипулирования таблицами, в котором определены операции над таблицами, результатом коих является всегда таблица. Не число, не скаляр, не вектор - а именно таблица (в терминах реляционной алгебры - реляция/отношение).

Теперь возвращаясь к нашим <strike>баранам</strike> ситуации: SQL именно по этой причине возвращает всегда таблицу. Местами это может быть и не очень удобно, занимает лишнюю память и все такое - но это плата за реляционную модель.

Например в Oracle, попытка напечатать число - приведет к выводу таблицы. Для таких случаем припасена специальная таблица `DUAL`:

```
select 123 as mynumber from dual;
```

выведет:

> mynumber
>
> ---
>
> ```
>   123
> ```

Comment: Вопрос же не про "почему SQL возвращает таблицу". Топикастер спросил, возвращается ли таблица как есть, в сыром виде, с передачей повторяющихся строк несколько раз, или используются какие-то механизмы дедупликации при передаче данных. Он спросил про внутреннее устройство протокола передачи таблицы. А вы ему про реляционную алгебру и dual ответили. :(